# Android Bluetooth multiple connection handling sockets

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-bluetooth

I'm trying to develop multiple bluetooth connection app. that are consist of more than 6 android devices

There would be a server and 5 clients.

Now server is waiting for client's attach with openning BluetoothServerSocket,

Clients will try to connect with UUID List(5 different uuid),

I'm trying to handle client sockets like this.

If the uuid that Client2 uses now is already used by Client1, client2 will change uuid to next one and retry to connect.

But whenever I tried to make connection with Client2 with same UUID that is used for Client1 is already connected to the server, no exception happens and client2 gets socket and IOstream as well.
(At this time, serverSocket.accept() is still blocked, which means it does not return socket on server side, because uuid is already used with client1 I think)

**How can I make a exception for this on client side to handle bluetooth connections?**

If there's no method for this,

I'm planning to make "sync protocol" between Server and client, and if there's no sync complete, client socket is closed after some time.